# Emailid validation using java regex

Tags: java, regex, jakarta-ee

Can anyone please help me to find out a solution of this problem using "java regex".

Question: The EmailId should be in the following format <<1st part>>.<<2nd part>>@<<3rd part>><<4th part>>

1st part should contain alpha numeric characters and it must contain at least 1 uppercase alphabet, 1 lowercase alphabet, and 1 number.

2nd part should contain alpha numeric characters.

3rd part should be an alphabetical value of length 3 to 8.

4th part can be “.com” or “.co.in”

My solution is:

```
if(EmailId.matches(""^(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{3,}\\.[\\w&&[^_]]+@[\\w&&[^_]]{3,8}\\.(com|co\\.in)")){
        return true;
}
```

But this solution is accepting "RAKESH1.Roshan@infy.co.in" this Email Id, which is not acceptable.

I don't know where I am going wrong.

Please help!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is not working because of `.` used in your pattern. If you do not allow all chars, you should only stick to specific classes of chars you allow.

I suggest:

```
.matches("(?=\\p{Alnum}*\\p{Upper})(?=\\p{Alnum}*[0-9])(?=\\p{Alnum}*\\p{Lower})\\p{Alnum}*[.]\\p{Alnum}+@\\p{Alpha}{3,8}[.]co(m|[.]in)"))
```

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/drD4oZ). Since the pattern is used with `.matches()`, no `^` at the start and `$` at the end anchors are necessary.

**Details**:

- `(?=\\p{Alnum}*\\p{Upper})` - Right from the start of the string, there must be an uppercase letter after 0+ alphanumeric chars
- `(?=\p{Alnum}*[0-9]) - Right from the start of the string, there must be a digit after 0+ alphanumeric chars
- `(?=\\p{Alnum}*\\p{Lower})`  - Right from the start of the string, there must be a lowercase letter after 0+ alphanumeric chars
- `\\p{Alnum}*` - 0 or more alphanumeric chars (replace `*` with `+` if you need to require at least 1)
- `[.]` - a literal `.` char
- `\\p{Alnum}+` - 1 or more alphanumeric chars
- `@` - a literal `@` char
- `\\p{Alpha}{3,8}` - 3 to 8 or more alphabetic chars
- `[.]co(m|[.]in)` - `.com` or `.co.in` at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your lookaheads aren't limited to the first part.

For example, with the input `RAKESH1.Roshan@infy.co.in`, the lookahead `(?=.*[a-z])` will skip `RAKESH1.R` and find the following lowercase `o`.

You can fix this by changing `.*` to `[^.]*` in all lookaheads.

---

Another problem is the `.{3,}`. This will match *any* character, not just alphanumeric ones. Change this to `[\\w&&[^_]]{3,}` (or just `[\\w&&[^_]]+`).

Comment: As per your suggestion, I changed my regex as: '^(?=[^.]*\\d)(?=[^.]*[a-z])(?=[^.]*[A-Z]).{3,}\\.[\\w&&[^_]]+@[\\w&&[^_]]{3,8}\\.(com|co\\.in)' but now it is accepting double dot after first part. example: 'Rishabh1..Roshan@infy.co.in'

Comment: @rishabh Oops, I missed that. It's because of your `.{3,}`. Answer updated.